# No installed components were detected. Element is already the child of another element

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In App.xaml I have added Application Resources with a button as:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="MyButton"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I tried to add this button programatically in my grid.

```
 Button btn = (Button)Application.Current.Resources["MyButton"];
 myGrid.Children.Add(btn);
```

But it gives error like this:

`No installed components were detected.  Element is already the child of another element.`

In MainPage.xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This exception is usually thrown if you're using more than one instance of the control you defined in your application resources. If that is the case, you should do:

```
<Button x:Key="MyButton" x:Shared="false"/>
```

EDIT: it seems WInRT doesn't support x:shared attribute.

There is a workaround using ControlTemplates: http://www.gdomc.com/0428/binding-the-content-property-of-a-contentcontrol-in-winrt/

Comment: I tried same but it gives error in app.xaml like this: `Syntax Error found in XBF generation`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the element that is already child of another element. It's like your child cannot be the child of another guy man.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. See https://www.newscientist.com/article/2107219-exclusive-worlds-first-baby-born-with-new-3-parent-technique/

Comment: @Paymon, that's lit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, but i did similar thing and I got the same mistake .
This didn`t work for me:

```
btn = new Button { Text = $"{i}", HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 };
flexLayout1.Children.Add(btn)
flexLayout2.Children.Add(btn)
```

But this worked:

```
flexLayout1.Children.Add(new Button { Text = $"{i}", HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 });
flexLayout2.Children.Add(new Button { Text = $"{i}", HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 });
```

Comment: Welacome to Stack Overflow! The second example works because C# is pass-by-reference. In the first example, you are trying to add the same button twice, but in the second example you create a new button every time. This does not really answear OP question though as he is trying to build a button from resources.